# How to add the 'features="html.parser"' in python

Tags: python, parsing, web, beautifulsoup

I have some code that is returning the error: 
UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("html.parser"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.

The code that caused this warning is on line 14 of the file scrape7.py. To get rid of this warning, pass the additional argument 'features="html.parser"' to the BeautifulSoup constructor.

My code is:

```
import numbers
import httplib2
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

http = httplib2.Http()
status, response = http.request('https://www.macys.com/social/the-edit/')

editurlslist = []

for link in BeautifulSoup(response, parse_only=SoupStrainer('a')):
    if link.has_attr('href'):
        if '/the-edit' in link['href']:
            editurlslist.append(str("https://www.macys.com"+link['href']))

products = []

for i in editurlslist:
   products.append(re.findall(r'(data-thisProduct=\"[0-9]{7}\")', 
   requests.get(i).text))

for i in editurlslist:
   products.append(re.findall(r'(productid=\"[0-9]{7}\")', 
   requests.get(i).text))

products2 = [x for x in products if type(x) in numberic_types]

print(products2)
```

Comment: `BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser', ...)`; the second argument is called `features`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the "html.parser" parameter to the BeautifulSoup constructor:

```
for link in BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser", parse_only=SoupStrainer('a')):
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Unfortunately, the following error is generated: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrape7.py", line 14, in <module>
    for link in BeautifulSoup(response, parser="html.parser", parse_only=SoupStrainer('a')):
  File "C:\Users\A089955\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 183, in __init__
    "__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument '%s'" % arg)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'parser'

Comment: @ScottDavis check the update

Comment: Thanks again AK47. It worked! Here's the final code excerpt: for link in BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser", parse_only=SoupStrainer('a')):